# Visualstudio cant pull from Team Foundation Server

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

If I try to pull I can see the incoming Commits, but there are no changes made and it still shows the commits which should come in.

Also, if I try to create a new branch from origin, it can't create one, but all changes from the chosen Branch are loaded in the master Branch.

I am working on a VM with Windows Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2015.

If I try to open the TFS from IE, IE crashes. I have IE 10.0.9200.22139 with Update Version 10.0.50.

Is there might an IE bug? So far I know Visual Studio uses IE in Background.

Comment: What does git from the command line show you? (If it doesn't work should at least give a clue to the issue.)

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'server': Failed to connect to server port 443: Timed out

Comment: It appears you have a network issue, unable to access https://<account>.visualstudio.com. Once you have that resolved then try git and/or Visual Studio again.

Comment: I found out the IE problem, IE 10 is not compatible with TFS. But it isn't a Network problem, because I can access every webpage.

Comment: Do you go through a proxy when connecting to the internet?

Comment: Yes, I found the error forgot to escape the backslash after the Domain in the .gitconfig file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error forgot to escape the backslash after the Domain in the .gitconfig file. Thanks for your help